# Why program is out of memory when in OS there is still plenty of?

Tags: c, out-of-memory

I added some features which require a lot of memory to a C program, it crashes everytime I run it, but it works fine when reduce the memory allocation. Using GDB to debug I find some bizarre results, like assignment would change other pointers, printf doesn't work. I thought this might be memory problem, but using `top` to monitor memory usage I find there is still plenty of memory.

Finally I used `Valgrind` to monitor memory, even valgrind ran out of memory:

```
==3449==     Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:
==3449==        memcheck:allocate new SecMap's request for 16384 bytes failed.
==3449==        7,625,605,120 bytes have already been mmap-ed ANONYMOUS.
==3449==     Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
==3449== 
==3449==     There are several possible reasons for this.
==3449==     - You have some kind of memory limit in place.  Look at the
==3449==       output of 'ulimit -a'.  Is there a limit on the size of
==3449==       virtual memory or address space?
==3449==     - You have run out of swap space.
==3449==     - Valgrind has a bug.  If you think this is the case or you are
==3449==     not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==3449==     Please note that programs can take substantially more memory than
==3449==     normal when running under Valgrind tools, eg. up to twice or
==3449==     more, depending on the tool.  On a 64-bit machine, Valgrind
==3449==     should be able to make use of up 32GB memory.  On a 32-bit
==3449==     machine, Valgrind should be able to use all the memory available
==3449==     to a single process, up to 4GB if that's how you have your
==3449==     kernel configured.  Most 32-bit Linux setups allow a maximum of
==3449==     3GB per process.
==3449== 
==3449==     Whatever the reason, Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
```

But using `ulimit -a` there is no limit on visual space:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 96254
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 96254
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Using `top` can tell server memory config:

```
KiB Mem : 24678616 total, 13461572 free,  3457528 used,  7759516 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 20754480 avail Mem
```

So what reason may caused this result?

---

update:

OS:

```
Linux astl09 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

program is [disksim 4.0](http://www.pdl.cmu.edu/DiskSim/index.shtml). I use it on some research.

valgrind:

```
valgrind-3.11.0
```

Comment: Does your programm use more than 3GB? Is your application 32Bit? Is valgrind 32Bit?

Comment: From the valgrind message, it's already using 7GB+, so not likely to be 32 bits. Still, more information about the OS, the program and the valgrind would be useful. Please edit the question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process - might be useful

Comment: Yes, it's using about 6GB. program is 64 bit, of course system is 64 bit. I don't know how to tell if valgrind is 32 bit, should it be 32 bit? I installed it by apt-get

Comment: @Arkadiy I updated question, Should I provide any more information?

Comment: @EdHeal It tells me how to limit my program, but all I want to do is free it. >_<

Comment: Please check the limits - is your current set up configured to be limited? If so, you have some information on how to proceed.

Comment: @EdHeal Seems not, I added no limit to program. And there is no limit inside code.